# SQL: check one table and enter values into another

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a very simple MS Access User Table (USER_TABLE) consisting of 3 fields:  `Customer_Number`, `User_Name`, and `Email_Address`.  I have another table (NEW_USERS) that consist of new requests for Users.  It has a `User_Status` field that is blank by default, and also has the `Customer_Number`, `User_Name`, and `Email_Address` fields.

Half of the new requests that come through are users already existing, so I want to set up a query that will check the USER_TABLE to determine if a new request exists or not, using the Email_Address field checked vs. the Customer_Number field.  Complicating this is the fact that 1) Customer_Number is not unique (many Users exists for a single Customer Number) and 2) Users can have multiple accounts for different Customer Numbers.  This results in 4 scenarios in the NEW_USERS table when checking vs. the USER_TABLE:

1. Email_Address does not exist for Customer Number in USER_TABLE (New)
2. Email_Address exists for Customer Number in USER_TABLE (Existing)
3. Email_Address does not exist for Customer Number in USER_TABLE, but exists for other Customer Numbers (New-Multi)
4. Email_Address does exist for Customer Number in USER_TABLE, and also exists for other Customer Numbers (Existing-Multi)

What I would like to do is run these checks and enter the corresponding result (New, Existing, New-Multi or Existing-Multi) into the User_Status field.

This seems like it would be possible.  Is it possible to run 4 separate queries to make the updates  to NEW_USERS.User_Status?

Comment: I figured it would be 4 separate queries...is that the easiest way?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I have edited the original question. I understand if no one wants to provide the queries.  I was not sure if they would be very complex or not.

Answer (score 0):

When you're working in Access, you really need a field that uniquely identifies each record.  At the very least, some combination of field, like customerid and email.

Beyond that, since you have a few criteria to satisfy, the easiest way is probably to make a single select statement that compares data between the results of multiple select statements.  Look into outer joins for picking the results from one table that are not found in another.  Something like -

```
insert into user_table select customerid, email_address from 
(select customerid, email_address from new_users inner join user_table on ...) as expr1, 
(select customerid, email_address from new_users outer join user_table on ...) as expr2 
where expr1.customerid = expr2.customerid and expr1.new_users = expr2.new_users
```

I recommend trying out the free stanford course on sql, theres a handy lesson on nesting your select statements - its a good way to get results that fit a lot of criteria.  http://class2go.stanford.edu/

As an aside, they do a lot using syntax of 'specifying joins in the where claus' which is increasingly frowned upon, but much easier to understand.